# Різниця між словами “винагорода” та “нагорода”

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Постало таке запитання: чи суттєвою або, можливо, навіть і критичною є різниця між словами "винагорода" та “нагорода" в контексті отримання оплати за виконану роботу, послугу тощо (наприклад: "грошова винагорода " чи "нагородна система установи")?

Офіційний сайт Української мови [зазначає](https://ukrainskamova.com/publ/slovnik_sinonimiv/n/nagoroda/36-1-0-9812), що ці слова є синонімами:

> **НАГОРОДА**
>
> Синоніми до слова НАГОРОДА: винагорода, ур. мзда, з. наділ; (на змаганнях) приз; (заохочення) премія; д. надгорода.

СУМ-11, напроти - розділяє ці два слова:

> [ВИНАГОРО́ДА](http://sum.in.ua/s/vynaghoroda), и, жін. Те, що є платою за працю, нагородою за які-небудь заслуги. Пунктуально о шостій годині прибули складачі, що за окрему винагороду зобов'язались до ранішньої роботи (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 252); Другого дня вони знайшли собі роботу в миловара — дрова пиляли та рубали. Винагорода — по півфунта мила (Юрій Збанацький, Сеспель, 1961, 167); 
>   //  Те, що дається або робиться замість чого-небудь втраченого; заподіяного і т. ін. Панство нас підтримало і внесло вимогу домагатися справедливої винагороди всім, хто постраждав у поході (Зінаїда Тулуб, Людолови, I, 1957, 11);  * У порівняннях. Потім у них народилося дитя. Це було вершиною їхнього щастя, було мовби гідною винагородою обом — і Уралову за всі життєві гіркоти, яких він зазнав, і Галі за її минуле невдале кохання (Олесь Гончар, Тронка, 1963, 299).
>
> [НАГОРО́ДА](http://sum.in.ua/s/naghoroda), и, жін. Відзначення заслуг, достоїнств і т. ін. Три Зорі у нагороду За геройство за твоє [Кожедуба]… (Іван Нехода, Ми живемо.., 1960, 114); 
>   //  Те, що дається для відзначення заслуг, достоїнств і т. ін. Коли мене викликали першого, щоб одержати нагороду [книжку], то я почув, що він [батько] голосно заплакав (Іван Франко, I, 1955, 12); Коли вручають нагороду Тобі чи області твоїй, — Подумай, що ти для народу В майбутнім зробиш, друже мій! (Степан Олійник, Вибр., 1959, 99).

Чи є принципова різниця між цими двома словами? 
Яке зі слів краще використовувати у тексті (в т.ч. і діловому написанні) або повсякденному спілкуванні для надання йому більшої відповідності? 
Хоча на перший погляд, "винагорода" має більше розповсюдження, в тому числі і в офіційних документах.

Answer (score 4):

Власне кажучи, у питанні закладено відповідь, а саме в нюансах значень, які ви навели у словникових статтях.

Спробуємо пірнути в суть за допомогою синонімів.

Винагородою є [платня](http://sum.in.ua/s/platnja), плата за роботу, службу, заробітна плата, те, що зароблене, заробіток, найчастіше гроші.

Нагородою є [відзнака](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidznaka) за заслуги в якій-небудь галузі, найчастіше предмет, що символічно заміняє винагороду або засвідчує досягнення, наприклад, диплом чи орден, Шевченківська премія тощо.

Answer (score 2):

Додам до відповіді Христини, що Вікіпедія також розмежовує ці поняття.

> [Нагоро́да](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B2._%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B6) — щось, що видається як заохочення за заслуги,
>   відзнаки, в знак подяки за що-небудь. Одним з призначень нагороди є
>   надання особливого соціального статусу особі що отримує нагороду.
>
> **До нагород відносять: почесні знаки, призи, премії, почесні грамоти, цінні подарунки та почесні звання.**
>
> [Винагорода](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) — цінності, які отримує особа в обмін на послуги
>   (роботи), які вона надала (виконала) для іншої особи. **Зазвичай
>   складається з грошової винагороди**, яка часто називається розрахунки
>   або заробітна плата. Проте, число додаткових вигод, як механізми
>   винагороди постійно збільшується.